# Keycloak 20.0.3 : Unrecognized field "otpPolicyCodeReusable"

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Try to update realResource with RealmRepresentation but when

```
 RealmRepresentation realmRepresentation = realmResource.toRepresentation();
```

I get

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "otpPolicyCodeReusable" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation), not marked as ignorable (135 known properties: "userFederationMappers", "rememberMe", "duplicateEmailsAllowed", "adminEventsDetailsEnabled", "users", "clientOfflineSessionMaxLifespan", "webAuthnPolicyRequireResidentKey", "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessAvoidSameAuthenticatorRegister", "components", "otpPolicyType", "accessCodeLifespanUserAction", "id", "webAuthnPolicyAttestationConveyancePreference", "enabledEventTypes", "applications", "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessSignatureAlgorithms", "eventsListeners", "ssoSessionMaxLifespanRememberMe", "defaultDefaultClientScopes", "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessCreateTimeout", "clientOfflineSessionIdleTimeout", "notBefore", "publicKey", "smtpServer", "clientPolicies", "resetPasswordAllowed", "webAuthnPolicyAvoidSameAuthenticatorRegister", "accessTokenLifespanForImplicitFlow", "webAuthnPolicyPasswordlessUserVerificationRequirement", "clientScopes", "internationalizationEnabled", "defaultRole", "accessTokenLifespan", "passwordCredentialGrantAllowed", "federatedUsers", "applicationScopeMappings" [truncated]])
at [Source: (org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse$InputStreamWrapper); line: 1, column: 1870] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation["otpPolicyCodeReusable"])
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:2023)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1700)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1678)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:319)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:2025)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1175)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.readFrom(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:193)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:101)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:80)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:217)
   ... 136 more
```

I'm using Keycloak Server 20.0.3 and Keycloak Admin REST Client 20.0.3 same version.

Comment: you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with the `otpPolicyCodeReusable` field being unrecognised when attempting to import a realm into Keycloak version 18. From looking at the `Keycloak` documentation for version 18, it appears that the `otpPolicyCodeReusable` field has been either deprecated or removed.

My solution was to simply remove that field from the realm resource, which was, in my case, a JSON file, and rerun the import. In your case, it looks like the realm resource is a Java object called realmResource. I am assuming that the `otpPolicyCodeReusable` field is also deprecated or removed in Keycloak version 20, in which case you would probably be able to just remove that field from the realmResource object and re-run your code.